# How to Connect remotely to the basic computer without having to disconnect another user

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, multiuser

I'am on Windows 7 OS, I'am wondering if there is a way to use my computer remotely which is located at my home, at the same time while someone from my family is already logged in with it's own username.

By default, when I'am trying to connect to my computer by using native Windows Remote Desktop Connection, it asks another already logged in user to disconnect, so i guess it's not enabled for multi-user session if I'am not getting it wrong.

So the question is, is it possible to make it multi session like, cause I didn't found any settings where I can change that.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with Windows 7 or any desktop version of windows without [replacing DLL's](http://www.blogsdna.com/2336/enable-multiple-user-accessconcurrent-user-sessions-for-remote-desktop-on-windows-7.htm) (This hack only works if you do not have SP1 installed, so you are leaving your self open to virus attacks that Microsoft has patched for, I do not recommend this approach).

If you want to support multiple users at the same time using the correct methods you will need to buy Windows Server 2008 R2 (the server version of Windows 7) or newer.